# Python accessing to wrong key

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm using a `dictionary` as an alternative to an `if/elif` structure that looks like this:

```
newValue = {
    'int': param.value + (random.choice((-1, 1)) * 
        random.randint(1, param.maxChange)),
    'float': param.value + random.uniform(-param.maxChange,
            param.maxChange),
    'bool': not param.value
}[param.dataType]
```

but when `param.dataType` is `'float'`, it access to the `'int'` value. If I use the `if/elif` structure, it works as expected.

```
if param.dataType == 'int':
    newValue = param.value + (random.choice((-1, 1)) * 
        random.randint(1, param.maxChange))

elif param.dataType == 'float':
    newValue = param.value + random.uniform(-param.maxChange,
        param.maxChange)

elif param.dataType == 'bool':
    newValue = not param.value
```

What could be wrong with the dict form? I'm using Python 2.7

***Edit:*** It wasn't that it was accessing to the wrong key. I was getting an exception belonging to the 'int' block of code, so I thought it was trying to assign the value from 'int' to newValue.

Comment: Have you tried putting the float choice before the int choice?

Comment: Could you please provide a working sample that shows the problem. The code you show does not include the creation/initialization of param.dataType.

Comment: In particular, what is the output of `print repr(param.dataType), type(param.dataType)`?

Comment: Also, how do you tell that a particular value has been accessed? In general, the `if/elif` structure looks much cleaner and makes more sense. With a dictionary, you calculate all 3 values and then only access one. A dictionary of _functions_ that would accept `param` instead of using the value from the current context would make sense, though.

Comment: How do you determine that the `'int'` value is being "accessed"? If it is that you get an error from `random.randint` about non-integer stops, then the reason is, as others have already pointed out, that all the alternatives are being calculated when constructing the `dict`.

Comment: That was the answer, an error. I read once that dictionaries are the preferred way to emulate switch-case in python. I guess that's not completely true. I'll also try to give a working example next time I ask something. Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code the dictionary is first instantiated and the `'int'`, `'float'`, and `'bool'` entries are added. As part of adding the entries, the expressions for `int`, `param.value + (random.choice((-1, 1)) * random.randint(1, param.maxChange))` as well as the other expressions are evaluated. This will lead to problems if the parameter does not have the correct data type. To fix it you could try the following: (untested because you did not provide a working example)

```
newValue = {
    'int': lambda param: param.value + (random.choice((-1, 1)) * 
        random.randint(1, param.maxChange)),
    'float': lambda param: param.value + random.uniform(-param.maxChange,
            param.maxChange),
    'bool': lambda param: not param.value
}[param.dataType](param)
```

Now the entries are holding lambda functions and the code should only be evaluated once called.

In addition, the dictionary has be created every time this code runs. If this part of the code runs multiple times, it should be more efficient to create the dictionary once and then use it multiple times.

Comment: That is indeed what was happening, it was evaluating everything and I was getting an error. Thank you!